# How do you create custom build rules in QTCreator for code generation?

Tags: qt-creator

I'm working on a GTK3 application, but using QTCreator as my IDE, just because I happen to like it. It works fine, I can easily turn off all the QT-specific stuff and link the GTK libraries. There's just one little issue.

GTK uses XML files to define its resources. It comes with a program, "glib-compile-resources", which takes a .gresource.xml file and produces a .c file*, which can then be included in your project. The problem is that QTCreator doesn't know about glib-compile-resources, so I have to remember to run the program manually every time I make any change to them.

I've tried using a custom build step, but if I do that, then QT rebuilds the file every time, even if it hasn't changed, which slows the process down. In addition, if the C file doesn't already exist, it will fail with a "No rule to make target 'x.c' needed by 'x.o'. Stop." error, so I have to run the program manually anyway.

Is there any way to tell QTCreator to run glib-compile-resources whenever it encounters a .gresource.xml file, and include the resulting C file into the final compilation?

*There are other options available then just a straight C source file, but C source is the simplest and easiest for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I wound up solving my own issue:

I found in the QT documentation how to [add your own custom compiler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers) to a QT project file. The exact lines needed are:

```
GLIB_RESOURCE_FILES += \
    resources.gresource.xml
    # Add more resource files here.

glib_resources.name = glibresources
glib_resources.input = GLIB_RESOURCE_FILES
glib_resources.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}.c
glib_resources.depend_command = glib-compile-resources --generate-dependencies ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
glib_resources.commands = glib-compile-resources --target ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} --sourcedir ${QMAKE_FILE_IN_PATH} --generate-source ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
glib_resources.variable_out = SOURCES
glib_resources.clean = ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += glib_resources
```

(Thanks to @zgyarmati, who's post lead me to the right answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom target in your qmake file (rather than in your QtCreator project config). See the qmake docs at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets and/or https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers.

Update: this is a simple example which shows how to do this for a single file, using the custom target mechanism in your .pro file:

```
glib_resources.target = glib-resources.c
glib_resources.depends = glib-resources.xml
glib_resources.commands = glib-compile-resources --target  $$glib_resources.target --generate-source $$glib_resources.depends


QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += glib_resources 
PRE_TARGETDEPS += glib-resources.c ## set this target as a dependency for the actual build
QMAKE_CLEAN += glib-resources.c  ## delete the file at make clean
```

Comment: I tried this, and got "No rule to make target 'glib-resources.xml', needed by 'glib-resources.c'. Stop." I did some searching and found [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets), but can't figure out how to configure the custom target.

Comment: I've edited my answer with actually using the $$glib_resources.depends variable. (which was a mistake i accidentally left in the demo code)  My guess would be that you changed only one occurrence of the "glib-resources.xml" filename. Now it's enough to do in the `glib_resources.depends = glib-resources.xml` line. If it still not working, pls post your .pro file (or at least the relevant section)

Comment: I thought of that, and I double-checked that I'd changed the name in both places. I even renamed my actual file to `glib-resources.xml` and just copy-pasted the code without modification. Still got the same error. However, your post did actually lead me to the right answer while I was searching that error message. So, even though I wasn't able to use your code, I did eventually figure out how to do it.